# How to access CD-ROM inside kvm guest machine?

Tags: linux, linux-kvm, scientific-linux

I am using KVM in Scientific Linux 6.4 
Inside that KVM again I installed Scientific Linux 6.4 as a guest.
Now I want to access CD-ROM from that guest machine.
In the command prompt it not showing any device file like /dev/cdrom and /dev/sr0 in guest machine.

So I tried add hardware option but it not showing any option like cdrom

[image]

So how to access CD-ROM from guest machine ?

**UPDATE**
While selecting IDE-CDROM I was getting this error
[image]

Comment: What are the options under `Device type`? Perhaps you can just select the ODD device as "other existing storage"? Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/373372/how-to-connect-a-cdrom-device-to-a-kvm-qemu-domain-using-command-line-tools

Comment: IDE DISK, IDE CDROM, Floppy disk, Virtio Disk, these 4 options are there.

Comment: ...well, what happens if you select `IDE CDROM`?

Comment: I was getting above error, I updated my question.

Comment: Try selecting an existing device or ISO file.

Comment: Thank you Bob it's working now. In 'Device Type' I selected IDE cdrom, and in that 'select managed or existing storage' I selected /dev/sr0.

Answer (score 0):

**update 01/11/22**

```
Alma Linux 8.6
```

No longer possible - stubbornly refuses to update drive while vm live and refuses based on whitelisting when vm offline. (see original note on why this is). Looks like 8.4 had a loophole and they plugged it.

**update 17/2/22** (as I was trying to do the same thing 4 yrs later...  )

```
Rocky Linux 8.4
```

using virt-manager (VMM) if you try to set the "file" to "/dev/cdrom" or "/dev/sr0" where you would normally put your iso ...

[image]

and then try to start the vm it will complain about white listing but if you do it once the vm is up and running it will work and you'll be able to access the cd/dvd in the vm ... I think there are virsh commands to do the same thing but you'll have to check that out yourself....

This may have been possible all along, dunno.

Back in 2018 I wrote ...

---

at time of writing....

**TL;DR** -  Can't be done out-of-the-box in RHEL/CentOS.

If you're using RHEL or CentOS, the host_cdrom block device is not available in the guest because the binaries are compiled with the host cdrom passthrough functionality disabled.

(various online posts suggest this is because Red Hat don't want to or can't support it)

see (bottom of) ; https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-virt/2017-April/005504.html